# What is the difference between language of empty string and empty set language?

Tags: formal-languages

I am reading Introduction to Automata theory by Ullman. It says the empty set and set containing empty string is different. I am unable to understand the difference between them as the empty string doesn't have any character.
Forgive me if this is dumb but I can't seem to understand it

Comment: $\emptyset$: it's a language containing no string: no element.
$\{\epsilon\}$: it's a language containing exactly one string, which has length 0 (the empty string, or "" if you will): one element.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The situation is the same with the *emptyset* and the number $0$ (*zero*).

$0$ is a *number* and the set $\{ 0 \}$ has one member, while the *emptyset* has **no** members at all.

*Numbers* are used to perform operations like "counting" objects; in order to correctly describe these operations, it is useful to introduce a number ($0$) that counts **no** objects.

In the same way, in order to describe the operations performed on *strings*, it is useful to introduce the string ($\epsilon$) with **no** symbols (that has $lenght=0$).

Comment: I get it. The empty set doesn't have an element but it differs from set containing empty string in that string operations can be performed on it.

Comment: @user3688659 - exactly; the theory of formal languages is **not** dealing with *sets*, but with *strings*; set language is used (in the meta-theory) to describe the "mechanism" of formal languages. This "mechanism" needs the *empty string*, which is a string with $0$ lenght.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a program that accepts the language that contains only the empty string:

```
    s = get_input();
    if (s == "") then ACCEPT;
    else REJECT;
```

Here is a program that accepts the empty language:

```
    s = get_input();
    REJECT;
```

They are not the same program! The first one accepts the empty string; the  second does not.

Answer (score 1):

The set containing one empty string has one element. The empty set has zero elements. The one with one element is "bigger" (its cardinality is larger).